# Question on definition of outer measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> A set $E$ is $\mu^* $ measurable if for each set $A$ we have $\mu^*(A)=\mu^*(A\cap E)+\mu^*(A \cap E^c)$.

Now the book I am reading says $\mu^*(A) \leq \cdots$ always hold. I am assuming this is due to the definition of outer measure was using inf of length of covers. And since $A\subset (A\cap E)\cup (A\cap E^c)$ we must have the cover of the union is also a cover of $A$. But as far as I'm concerned $A$ and $(A\cap E)\cup (A\cap E^c)$ are the same set and why can't I use the same logic to argue the reverse of the inequality?

Comment: Outer measure is not additive on all non-measurable sets.  There exist disjoint $B,C$ with $B\cup C=[0,1]$ and $\mu^*(A)=\mu^*(B)=1$. There seems to be a recent style of teaching measure theory without mentioning $inner$ measure.  Let $c(A)$ be the set of closed subsets of $A$. Define $\mu^i(A)=\sup \{\mu^*(B): B\in c(A)\}$. When  $\mu^*(A)<\infty$ we have: $A$ is measurable iff $\mu^*(A)=\mu^i(A).$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is due to subadditivity of $\mu^*$ (it is an outer measure). An outer-measure a-priori has nothing to do with covers. Sure, you could start with a more primitive set function (a premeasure $\mu_0$) defined on a smaller collection of sets, and then define a corresponding outer-measure $\mu^*$, but still, all we know is that $\mu^*$ is subadditive. So, $A=(A\cap E)\cup (A\cap E^c)$ implies the inequality
\begin{align}
\mu^*(A)\leq \mu^*(A\cap E)+\mu^*(A\cap E^c).
\end{align}
I'm still not seeing your reverse inequality argument.

Note that this **definition** tells us what a ($\mu^*$-)measurable set is; it is one for which equality holds (a non-trivial condition). And this equality condition roughly speaking encodes the condition of "outer measure equals inner measure".

Comment: I understand now, thank you. I was mistakenly thinking that inequality holds trivially due to monotonicity instead.